# C Function Skipped at Runtime

Tags: c, function, runtime, void

I have the following C code in a program:

```
printf("Test before print_foo()");
void print_foo(char board[ROW][COL]);
printf("Test after print_foo()");
```

where print_foo printf's the passed in 2-D character array with proper .c and .h files imported.

Console output is only the two printf statements.
Debugging, the run-time never even steps into print_foo.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oops. Thanks guys for the prompt responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void print_foo(char board[ROW][COL]);
```

is not a function call. It's a declaration.

You probably want

```
print_foo(board);
```

Comment: The "you probably want" line is probably incorrect. See Alex Martelli's answer for slightly more context and a more likely answer.

Answer (score 3):

That `void` prefix is making the middle line into a declaration of function `print_foo` (and the `char` within the parentheses means it would be invalid syntax otherwise).  To just **call** `print_foo`, change the middle line to `print_foo(board);` (if `board` is how you named that 2-D character array).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a function declaration to me - that's why your foo-nction is not being called.

Answer (score 2):

Your middle line is just a function declaration, not a function call.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't declare the prototype previously then you have to write this :

```
printf("Test before print_foo()");
void print_foo(char board[ROW][COL]);
print_foo(board);
printf("Test after print_foo()");
```

In short you have to define/declare print_foo before invoking,or your compiler will flag an error !!